# LC_ALL: cannot change locale

Tags: debian, locale

When I log into my server (Debian 7) through PuTTY, I get greeted by a message saying:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_GB.UTF-8).
```

Then, when I try to run almost any command I get this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_GB:en",
        LC_ALL = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I have looked all over the web for help. My /etc/environment file has 'LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"' within it.

Typing;

```
locale -a
```

prints the following:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

This is the result of locale-gen:

```
root@vps94194:/# locale-gen
-bash: locale-gen: command not found
```

The same goes for the update-locale command.

I cannot reinstall the locale through aptitude as the error blocks it. I can't use dpkg to reconfigure for the same reason.

I really don't know how to fix this. Nothing so far has made any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

and install what is needed via `aptitude` (`locales` package or something equivalent).

If you still get some error due to previous failure, first run:

```
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: This gets rid of the perl errors but aptitude is erroring:
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts

Comment: @Briggy I've completed my answer: `apt-get install -f` should fix problems. Otherwise your system is in a seriously broken state.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I had to remove a symbolic link, but after that everything worked fine. You're a lifesaver :)

Comment: @Briggy See [Here](https://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html) after exporting `LC_ALL`

Answer (score 3):

I was using German VPS and couldn't change locale because there was no English language pack installed.

After installing I could finally change locale

```
aptitude install language-pack-en
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding the following rule to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  SetEnv LC_ALL=C
```

Assuming your SSH server got the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Check also: `man ssh_config` and `man sshd_config`.